# AngularJS: What is wrong with this injection into my controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building up a simple task management system with AngularJS and am currently playing with it and mocking the data up. I have a problem with the injection of a service into my ProjectCtrl controller and I cannot wrap my head around it.

At the bottom of this code: Why is the projects variable in the ProjectsCtrl controller just an empty array? It should contain the mockup data, no? What am I doing wrong?

Please excuse this maybe very stupid question. I just don't find my mistake.

```
angular.module("TaskManager", ['ui.router'])
.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: '/home.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
            .state('projects', {
                url: '/projects/{id}',
                templateUrl: '/projects.html',
                controller: 'ProjectsCtrl'
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
    }
])
.factory('projects', [function(){
    var o = {
        projects: []
    };
    return o;
}])
.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope', 
    'projects', 
    function($scope, projects){

        $scope.projects = projects.projects;

        $scope.projects = [
            {title: "project 1", done: 0},
            {title: "Another project 2", done: 0},
            {title: "project 3", done: 1},
            {title: "project 4", done: 0},
            {title: "project 5", done: 0},
        ];

        $scope.addproject = function() {

            if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return };

            $scope.projects.push({
                title: $scope.title,
                comment: $scope.comment,
                done: 0,
                tasks: [
                    {title: 'Task 1', comment: 'Kommentar 1', done: 0},
                    {title: 'Task 2', comment: 'Kommentar 2', done: 0}
                ]
            });

            $scope.title = "";
            $scope.comment = "";
        }

        $scope.markAsDone = function(project) {
            project.done = 1;
        }
    }
])
.controller('ProjectsCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$stateParams',
    'projects', 
    function($scope, $stateParams, projects){
        $scope.project = projects.projects[$stateParams.id];

        // Why is this an empty array?
        console.log(projects);
    }
])
```

For completion: This is the HTML part:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TaskManager</title>

        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="TaskManager">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <ui-view></ui-view>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>TaskManager</h1>
        <a href="#/test">TEST</a>
      </div>

      <div ng-repeat="project in projects | orderBy: ['done','title']">
        <span ng-click="markAsDone(project)">Done</span>
        {{project.title}} - done: {{project.done}}
        <span>
          <a href="#/projects/{{$index}}">Tasks</a>
        </span>
        <p ng-show="project.comment">Comment: {{project.comment}}</p>
      </div>

      </hr> 

      <form ng-submit="addproject()" style="margin-top: 30px;">
        <h3>Add new project</h3>
        <input type="text" ng-model="title" placeholder="project"></input>
        <br><br>
        <textarea name="comment" ng-model="comment"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Post</button>
      </form>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="/projects.html">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h3>Project: {{project.title}}</h3>
      </div>

      <div ng-repeat="task in project.tasks | orderBy: ['done','title']">
        {{task.title}} - done: {{task.done}}
        <p ng-show="task.comment">Comment: {{task.comment}}</p>
      </div>

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never assign the values to `projects.projects`. In `MainCtrl`, you assign `$scope.projects` to the value of `projects.projects` (which is an empty array at that point). Then after that you overwrite `$scope.projects` with a totally new and different array, so you never end up modifying `projects.projects`.

I would move functions that let you add, remove, update items to `projects` service, but in the interim you can assign `projects.projects` first and then assign that to `$scope.projects`.

Better `projects` service:

```
.factory('projects', function() {
  var projects = [];
  return {
     add: function(item) {
        // your additional code
        projects.push(item);
     },
     remove: function(item) {
       // your additional code
       var i = projects.indexOf(item);
       if (i >=0) projects.splice(i,1);
     },
     get: function() {
         return projects;
     },
     initialize: function(items) {
       projects = items;
     }
  };
});
```

Then you can use this in your controller:

```
 .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, projects) {
    projects.initialize([ ... ]);
    $scope.projects = projects.get();
    $scope.addproject = function() {
        // NOTE: move whatever code you feel is or could be the responsibility of the service to the add method. I left this function as-is though, so you have a frame of reference.

        if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return };

        projects.add({
            title: $scope.title,
            comment: $scope.comment,
            done: 0,
            tasks: [
                {title: 'Task 1', comment: 'Kommentar 1', done: 0},
                {title: 'Task 2', comment: 'Kommentar 2', done: 0}
            ]
        });

        $scope.title = "";
        $scope.comment = "";
    };

    // etc.
 });
```

I recommend making the service the single point of authority so you can test logic pertaining to interacting with the service and its data, and avoid repeating yourself when different controllers and directives need to interact with the service or its data. It'll also help you avoid these sorts of issues where the data becomes out of sync between different controllers, directives, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am just learning AngularJS and got confused. But in the end it is a very simple M(V)C pattern and not so different from, say, Rails. And of course data manipulation belongs in the model/factory and not in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

When you're setting up the mock data, you're only setting them on $scope.projects...the factory's projects is never updated. You could flip it around and it should work:

```
projects.projects = [<mock data>];
$scope.projects = projects.projects;
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your mocked data in factory and remove the initialization in your controller.

```
angular.module("TaskManager", ['ui.router'])
.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: '/home.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
            .state('projects', {
                url: '/projects/{id}',
                templateUrl: '/projects.html',
                controller: 'ProjectsCtrl'
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
    }
])
.factory('projects', [function(){
 var o = {
         projects: [
            {title: "project 1", done: 0},
            {title: "Another project 2", done: 0},
            {title: "project 3", done: 1},
            {title: "project 4", done: 0},
            {title: "project 5", done: 0},
        ]
    };
    return o;

}])
.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope', 
    'projects', 
    function($scope, projects){

        $scope.projects = projects.projects;


        $scope.addproject = function() {

            if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return };

            $scope.projects.push({
                title: $scope.title,
                comment: $scope.comment,
                done: 0,
                tasks: [
                    {title: 'Task 1', comment: 'Kommentar 1', done: 0},
                    {title: 'Task 2', comment: 'Kommentar 2', done: 0}
                ]
            });

            $scope.title = "";
            $scope.comment = "";
        }

        $scope.markAsDone = function(project) {
            project.done = 1;
        }
    }
])
.controller('ProjectsCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$stateParams',
    'projects', 
    function($scope, $stateParams, projects){
        $scope.project = projects.projects[$stateParams.id];

        // Why is this an empty array?
        console.log(projects);
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the way to go. I am just learning AngularJS and got confused while following a tutorial. Of course the mockup data belongs to the model / factory and not the controller